# What our students have to say. Grammar question

Tags: grammar, word-usage, ambiguity

I often hear the phrase "what our students have to say" in testimonials, and I am confused with the grammar here.

It can be taken in two ways as follows.

1) Our students have something (what) to say
2) Our students have to say something (what).

I think 2) is more likely it since it sounds like an honest opinion.

Could anyone give some insights into this?

Comment: If, by (2), you mean "Our students are required to say something", then, no.  It means our students have something to say.

Comment: Meanings (1) and (2) are pronounced differently in standard English. The first uses /v/ and the second /f/.

Comment: Hi Scott,
Thank you for your prompt replies. I was thinking of something like
"What do you think of the movie?"
"I have to say it is quite boring."

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thank you. but In writing, it is difficult to know whether is pronounced f or v. like this
http://belmont.edu/languages/areas-of-study/german/what_our_students_have_to_say.html

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about two meanings of *have*.  The first is to hold or possess, and idiomatically we talk about holding an opinion as "having something to say."  The second is to be under complusion, as in

> I have to go to the dentist today.

So, you're right:

> Let's listen to what our students have to say

can have (see what I did there?) two meanings, either let's listen to our students' own opinions or let's listen to them parrot what they've been told to say.

Comment: And those two meanings of *have* can and do lead to confusion. *What do you have to do tonight?* It must be especially difficult for a newcomer to English to grasp when one is intended and not the other. So although the OP's question is not well articulated I do understand the problem.

Comment: So this is an ambiguous sentence which can be taken in two meanings especially in writing. Am I right?

Comment: No; the expressions involved are the main verb _have_ and the semi-modal _have to_ (sense 'must').

Comment: @NickCostello Native speakers will likely take sense 1) first, and some will realize that sense 2) slyly undercuts sense 1).  It is ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

Let's listen to what our students have to say. =

Let's hear opinions/testimonials from our students.

( 'have' is the verb, and 'to' is part of the infinitive of the next verb.)

For example:What do we have to eat?, meaning, What food is there available to eat?

Comment: Thank you, Cathy. I understand what it means.But my problem is why you need " have to(modal verb like must)" there.  Can it be simply "what our students say"? Why you need " have to" there. Does "have to" add some other nuance to the phrase? Or It means "what / our students / have (verb) / to say"?

Comment: @NickCostello You can also say: Let's hear what our students say. But the other way is more common. 'have to', however, is not being used as a modal of obligation. It's just an expression, similar to: What have you got to say for yourself? or: I have something to say.

Comment: So, it doesn't make much difference whether this "have" is taken as a verb or as a part of modal verb, have to.

Comment: @NickCostello 'have' is the verb, and 'to' is part of the infinitive of the next verb.

Comment: Sorry. since must is considered a modal verb,  I thought its equivalent, have to, is also considered modal verb.
My last question (favor). 
Is it correct to use  "have to(must) say" to express your opinions?
For example,
I have to say the play was abysmal.
If so, does it sound like honest, truthful opinions to you?

Comment: @NickCostello In the example: Let's listen to what our students have to say. - 'have' is the verb, and 'to' goes with 'say', so it's not 'have to', which is a modal of obligation. In the latest example, I have to say...'have to' is the modal, and it expresses a personal feeling of obligation to express your opinion. 'have' and 'to' are not always together as a modal. For example : What do we have to eat? 'to' goes with 'eat', meaning, What food is there to eat? - there's no obligation, or modal of obligation.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear although I still feel the sentence is ambiguous since "what we have to eat" can mean "what we must eat." depending on the context. In speaking, the sounds f and v and the intonation  can usually tell them apart, but in writing it is difficult, especially for ESL students like me. So the "have to say" expression in testimonials, I feel like it is used to talk about students' true personal feelings about the program they participated in. Anyway, thank you for your insights. I appreciate it.

Comment: @NickCostello There are two interpretations, obviously. In the original example, it's not obligation.